# Testing Facebook app on VB.NET WebBrowser - IFrame Access Deined - Cross-Domain Scripting

Tags: vb.net, facebook, iframe, browser

I have a facebook iframe app I'm trying to test using a WebBrowser Control on a form in VB.NET 2010. Whenever I try to access the WebBrowser.Document.Window.Frames frame object on a document where my app is showing in the broswer, I get an Access Denined exception. Reading around on the web, I see people saying that this is to keep scripts in a document from accessing content in iframes that are pulling content from another domain, as per 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028.aspx', for security reasons.

While I totally understand why this is done for the general public, how can I disable it on my machine so that I can run these tests? I can't properly test my app without doing it in the facebook iframe and using the WebBrowser control is the only way I know to do this test programmatically.

Any ideas? I'm on windows server 2003 and ie8, .net4.0, if that helps. I own the domain where the app is, and its in AS.NET MVC2, so if there's anything I can do to the web code to enable this??? I also removed the Internet Explorer ENhanced Security COnfiguaration component, but that didn't help.

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your Internet Explorer settings to enable cross domain scripting?

I believe the VB.Net Web Browser control inherits settings from the local copy of IE.

Try this:
From Internet Explorer, choose Internet Options from the Tools menu.
On the Security tab of the Internet Options dialog box, select the Local Intranet Web Content Zone and then click Custom Level.
Locate the Miscellaneous/**Access Data Sources Across Domains** setting, and then select Enable, as shown in Figure 2.
Click OK, and then click Yes to the warning dialog box that appears.
Click OK to close the Internet Options dialog box.

Also try adding the Facebook https Url into your trusted sites.

As a last resort disable Native XMLHttp in IE and attempt to revert back to an older version of the XMLHttp object.

Comment: Hi. THanks for the reply. I tried the internet options suggestion and put all the sites I could think of in the trusted sites. No luck. Still get {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"} System.UnauthorizedAccessException
 on every property that reads anything from the frame I want.